# How to get or split some specific json value using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel-5

I managed to used `GuzzleHttp\Client` and `json_decode` in order to retrieve the JSON responses from an API.

See results below:

```
    [{
        "INDEX": "1",
        "DESCRIPTION": "1; 0; US; United States of America;"
    },
    {
        "INDEX": "2",
        "DESCRIPTION": "1; 0; CN; China;"
    },
    {
        "INDEX": "3",
        "DESCRIPTION": "1; 0; MY; Malaysia;"
    },
    {
        "INDEX": "4",
        "DESCRIPTION": "1; 0; JP; Japan;"
    },
    {
        "INDEX": "5",
        "DESCRIPTION": "1; 0; MX; Mexico;"
    },
    {
        "INDEX": "6",
        "DESCRIPTION": "1; 0; SG; Singapore;"
    }]
```

---

But now, I only want to get some of the values in the "DESCRIPTION" inorder to save in a logfile but I don't know how split it. Can someone help me how to split it using `foreach loop` or `for loop`? Or any method to get the result?

I just want it to be like this:

```
[
{
    "CATEGORY" : "COUNTRIES",
    "LISTS" : [
        {
            "NAME": "United States of America",
            "CODE": "US"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "China",
            "CODE": "CN"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "Malaysia",
            "CODE": "MY"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "Japan",
            "CODE": "JP"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "Mexico",
            "CODE": "MX"
        },
        {
            "NAME": "Singapore",
            "CODE": "SG"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: What about `json_decode()` ?

Comment: You can take a look at the [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written this code with mobile and I have not tested it. Hope to be useful.

```
$my_array=json_decode($json,true);
$output=[];
foreach ($my_array as $value)
{
    $explode_array= explode(';',$value['DESCRIPTION']);
    $output[]=[
        'NAME'=>trim($explode_array[3]),
        'CODE'=>trim($explode_array[2])
    ];
}
$target=[
    'CATEGORY'=>'COUNTRIES',
    'LISTS'=>$output
];
var_dump($target);
```

`$json` is your `JSON` responses from an API.

Comment: your codes is almost perfect and very userful :), but the result I get has space after the open quotation mark on it, 
like this:
 `{
  "NAME": " United States of America",
  "CODE": " US"
 },`
I try to debug it. I add one space after the semicolon ('; '). But the problem is the "NAME" param includes the semicolon :( 
Like this:

 `{
  "NAME": "United States of America;",
  "CODE": "US"
 },`

Comment: Cool! It works! I'll marked this as the correct answer. Thank you for the help!